# How to build a docker image for deployment to production server

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, deployment

I have read some of the basic docs on how to build a docker image for a Node app. So I made one using this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json"]

RUN npm install             # Installing dependencies is making image HUGE

COPY /dist ./               # Copy the fully-built app 

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ] # This is not important
```

I am trying to send this docker image to a server and the image file is huge, like 1.2GB. So doing a deployment with this is unfeasible.

Is there a better way to doing deployments using a docker image for a web app? Ideally I would like to upload the docker image that contains all the `dist` folder files AND THEN install the dependnencies to make the app work.

Am I thinking wrongly or is there any guidance on how a proper Docker workflow works?

Comment: Actually, you don't send image to server directly. You should push the image to docker hub(e.g https://hub.docker.com/), than you pull the image from the hub to your server

Comment: Are you installing your application's `devDependencies`; does setting `ENV NODE_ENV=production` before you `RUN npm install` (or `npm ci`) help?

Comment: @frank_lee no we do it using docker save to make a .tar file and then docker load.

Comment: @DavidMaze adding `npm install --omit=dev` helped considerably and reduced the size to 400MB. Is that still a lot? Its going to a take LONG time to upload this for every deployment making docker useless for CI/CD.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a lot to me; how large is the `node_modules` directory?  If your CI system is able to successfully use the Docker layer cache then it may be able to avoid re-uploading the earlier layers and only push the layer with the actual application code, which will help this case.

Comment: @DavidMaze The app itself in the `dist` folder is only about 30MB, so the rest is `node_modules` so it will be some 380MB I guess. I zipped the docker .tar file and it brought it down to 120MB which has to be uploaded but the size of the app will only grow.